# Java Swing form model view controller

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm a little bit confused about imlementing MVC architecture on my application.
I have a JFrame with form inside it. I when the user clicks okBtn to send the data to the controller.
What's the way to do this.

Comment: [Oracle tutorials - MVC with java swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-142890.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button event, you make an instance of class controller then you send the parameters by calling the method

Comment: Yes, i've created the controller as member in my view class.So, do i need to create a methode in my controller with 10 parmaters, and call it from my view and pull it with view informations ?

Comment: of course you write a method then you call it with 10 parameters

Comment: is this considered the best way to do this.

Comment: it is the MVC architecture

Comment: thank you, for clarfication

Answer (score 0):

The fields of the form should be backed up by Document instances which should be bundled in an instance of some class modelling the form. This instance is sent to the Controller.

PArameter lists of length 10 aren't really "in style".